# how to flash Kindle Fire with custom boot.img

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, rom-flashing

I tried flashing my Kindle Fire with a custom `boot.img` using this command:

```
$ fastboot -b 0x80000000 -i 0x1949 flash boot boot.img && fastboot reboot

sending 'boot' (3536 KB)...
OKAY [  0.889s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.858s]
finished. total time: 1.746s
rebooting...
ERROR: usb_read failed with status e00002ed

finished. total time: 0.001s

$
```

but it always gets stuck in Fastboot Mode (requiring recovery mode). What's the correct command to get a successful flash?

Comment: It looks like it's flashing fine, just failing to reboot. Do you get the same result if you execute the flash and reboot separately (like as completely independent commands)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried them separately, but it's the same result. The reboot itself doesn't actually fail as the error message above might suggest. The `usb_read` fails because the device has rebooted.

Comment: Does a hot boot work? i.e. `fastboot boot boot.img`

Comment: That has the same result. :(

Comment: Weird, I never had this much trouble flashing images in fastboot. Are you using the stock bootloader or FIREFIREFIRE?

Comment: FIREFIREFIRE. I've Googled a bit and couldn't anyone using the stock bootloader on Fire. Maybe the stock doesn't work for custom ROMs. The only way I can flash a custom kernel is by including it in an update.zip and loading that from TWRP (that whole process takes several minutes). There's gotta be an easier way from the command line.